# Parse multiple RSS feeds (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, rss, feedparser

Using Feedparser to parse multiple RSS feeds but this function doesn't work. How can I create a function to parse feeds and get the link out of the feed entry to further push to a tweet?

```
def get():
    rss_url = [
    'http://www.huffingtonpost.com/news/syria/feed/',
    'http://www.nytimes.com/svc/collections/v1/publish  /www.nytimes.com/topic/destination/syria/rss.xml',
    ]

def getHeadlines(rss_url):
    feeds = []
    for url in rss_url:
        feeds.append(feedparser.parse(url))

    for feed in feeds:
        for post in feed.entries:
            return post.link

tweet(getHeadlines(rss_url))
```

I am able to do it when I try just this -

```
RSS_URLS = [
'http://feeds.feedburner.com/RockPaperShotgun',
'http://www.gameinformer.com/b/MainFeed.aspx?Tags=preview',
]

feed = feedparser.parse(RSS_URLS)

for post in feed.entries:
    print post.title
```

Comment: What does "to no avail" mean in this context? In what way does this code not do what you expect? Please read [ask] for tips on asking effective questions; this is the single biggest thing you can do to increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: I expect the code to parse the feeds and derive the link of each entry in the feed. It is not doing that when I define a function.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code block. Right now it isn't clear what lines are part of `getHeadlines()` and what lines aren't.

Comment: Fixed. Hope it's better now?

Answer (score 0):

`return`ing in a loop doesn't cause a list of things to be returned; it causes the function to return immediately.

In this case you will only ever get the result of the first loop iteration (the first link from the first post in the first feed). Have a look at the return value of your current `getHeadlines(rss_url)` to see what I mean.

Instead, you could build a list of links similarly to how you are building a list of `feeds` and return that:

```
links = []
for feed in feeds:
    for post in feed.entries:
        links.append(post.link)

return links
```

I'm not sure what `tweet()` is supposed to be, but you'll probably have to tweet each element in your list individually.

Comment: Do you mean creating another list of URLs? Could you explain a bit further?

Comment: @codenovice, I've updated my answer. Please see if it is clear now.